# C - passing argument 1 of ‘fprintf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, printf

Very simple script throw this error :

> passing argument 1 of ‘fprintf’ makes pointer from integer without a
>   cast

Why is that ? The code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *FP;

if((FP = fopen("file.txt", "r+")) == NULL) {
    printf("File won't open\n");
    return(1);
}

foo(FP);

return(0);
}

int foo(FP) {

    char name[31];
    printf( "Please enter a name (within 30 char) : \n");
    gets(name);
    fprintf(FP, "%s\n", name);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Oh, where did you see  `gets()`? Old resource definitely. Don't use `gets()` use `fgets()`. What is `FP`? And this is not a script, it's a program. It's not the same. Scripts are programs that run with interpreters, there is no [tag:c] interpreter.

Comment: `FP` is expected to be of type `FILE *`. Show the full code.

Comment: I love these questions that leave out the important parts. What is `FP`? Where is it declared and defined?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy paste the boilerplate code (`main()` function, `FILE *FP`, etc) and extracted the problem to easier reading.

Comment: Would your compiler compile this *easier reading* part?

Comment: I thought it was obvious as `fprintf` prints in a FILE.

Comment: For easier reading of our crystal balls, you mean. Could `FP` be a macro that gets in the way of your `FILE *` definition?

Comment: No it does not compile and throw the above error

Comment: Ok I updated with the boilerplate code. Is my problem clearer now ?

Comment: Your code looks ok, omiting return at the end of main(); Is this your real code?

Comment: @LPs: Which is OK by the standard. (In `main()` only, implies `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`.)

Comment: Which compiler and which flags do you use? This might be a very localised problem.

Comment: Ok, well it's updated now. It doesn't even compile, due to the above error.

Comment: What is your platform? Which compiler? Compiler flags?

Comment: The code you posted compiles fine (warnings about `gets()`, and unused `argc` and `argv` nonwithstanding). GCC 4.8.4. Either you posted the wrong code, or there's something funny with how you're calling the compiler.

Comment: I don't know how to answer this. I use the `gcc` command in mac os x's terminal to compile.

Comment: Could you post your gcc command?

Comment: `gcc --version` outputs : (GCC) 4.2.1

Comment: My gcc command is `gcc file.c`. Which compiles into `a.out`. Which I run to see the results.

Comment: I won't believe this doesn't compile till you post a screenshot of the results of `cat yourfile.c` immediately followed by `gcc -Wall yourfile.c`. Where `yourfile.c` should be **exactly** that code you have posted.

Comment: @lapin: The code you posted *looks* fine, and *compiles* fine. There's a problem elsewhere.

Comment: Take a look [HERE](https://ideone.com/rXXV1m). The posted code compiles...

Comment: @mikedu95 wrong link. I corrected

Comment: You were all true. The previous code actually compiled. I got misleaded by the error which implied the `fprintf` was doing something wrong. Please see the updated question.

Comment: ah.. you left the only part that matter for the last. You got it wrong: it's leave the best for the last.

Comment: `int foo(FP) {` does not make sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
int foo(FP) {
```

to

```
int foo(FILE * FP) {
```

You must put a prototype of `foo` function at the top of your code.

Comment: @lapin you don't have to... and LPs has made the correct additional remark that `foo()` should be dclared before use. Either you write a line declaring it somewhere (on top of the file or in a header, possibly); or you move the whole function definition -- which is also a declaration -- to the top of the file.

Comment: Ok, if YOU allow me then fair enough, I changed it to LPs : )

Answer (score 1):

The parameter FP in the declaration of `foo(FP)` has no type which makes it default to `int`. Because `foo` uses it as the first parameter in a call to `fprintf`, the int gets converted to a `FILE` pointer which is legal but deprecated.

Fix: Simply declare `foo` as `int foo(FILE *FP){...}`.

Edit: And yes, as LPs said, you should declare the function before use, especially if you pass or return other types than int to or from it. The declaration can either be separate from the definition, possibly in a header; or you simply move the function definition, which is also a declaration, to a place before its first use.

Answer (score 1):

By default the function arg in C has type int. So when you define your function the signature actually is

```
int foo(int FP).
```

You should change it to

```
int foo(FILE *FP)
```

And, of course, it would be nice to declare function before call it.

Comment: Thank you for your easy to understand answer !

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the type classifier in FP parameter in the Foo function. Surprisingly you didn´t get an warning about it. 
when you are compiling, please turn on the `-Wall` and `-pedantic` flag (if you are on `gcc`). or at least the `-Wimplicit-int` warning flag to avoid similar problems